# how to make lua config file to be safe

Tags: lua, configuration-files

I am new to **Lua** and want to ask whether it is possible to restrict lua syntax in config file? I know that config loading have to be performed in jail, but how we can cope with `while 1 do end` in config file we want to load? Is there a way to allow only strings, assignments and tables in config and if not, then what is the best way to check that lua file doesn't contain undesirable constructs? Is manual pre-parsing the only solution?

Answer (score 7):

You seem to already know about "sandboxing" in Lua.  So what's left is as you say malicious constructs like infinite loops.  And to solve that you need to solve the Halting Problem.  Which is not practical.

Instead of "manually" parsing and hoping you find all the malicious content (you won't), how about just running your Lua interpreter with a timer set so that the script will be interrupted if it takes longer than N seconds?

Comment: +1 for practical solution rather than solving it using the other hard way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly forbid certain constructs in Lua, you have to actually scan the file yourself. Note that there are valid uses for those constructs, even in config files, so you are restricting what the user can do.

It wouldn't be too hard to write a simple Lua lexer that ignores the contents of strings and comments, but errors on any of the Lua keywords other than `return`. Given proper sandboxing (ie: no functions are available to be called), that should be sufficient to weed out anything malicious.

Also, note that Lua 5.1 doesn't make it easy to keep the parser from parsing non-text data (ie: compiled Lua bytecode). 5.2 offers specific API support for forcing the loader to only recognize text and therefore reject bytecode.